# Duplicity 'No Such file or Directory'

Tags: duplicity

I am trying to run duplicity to backup our dataserver to an external server over sftp.
My command is as follows:

```
duplicity --no-encryption /home/dataserver sftp://user@host --ssh-askpass
```

When i run this i get errored with:

```
BackendException: ssh connection to user@host failed: No such file or directory: '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
```

Comment: try to run only `ssh user@host` to create missing file

Answer (score 0):

Let's create and fill this file.

Run these commands from user you will run `duplicity`, for example from `dataserver` (If your user is already `dataserver`, then skip first step):

```
sudo -u dataserver -i
mkdir -m 0700 -p ~/.ssh
ssh-keyscan your-host.example.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

P.S.: It looks like you run `duplicity` from user account `user`, so skip first step.